# How to create (and be able to change) global variables in SailsJS

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

I know there are [globals](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/globals) in Sails but they seem pretty static. I tried just doing `sails.config.globals.test = 1;` in `globals.js` but it didn't seem to *actually* be present globally. I'm looking for some sort of global variables that I change during run-time.

Comment: you're able to access global variable but can't change it? right?

Comment: You're able to access variables you create in `sails.config`, but correct, you cannot change them.

Comment: That's more of a node.js question rather than sails.js specific. In node, you can assign variables to the global object. So within you sails application. You can do something like `global.myGlobalVariable = 'hello, world'`

Comment: Well you could use Redis. Or any other database.